# Vue.js: Using prerendered html as template for parent and child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently rendering all the html server-side and I'm trying to get vue to use this html as the `$el` for the following two components. As far as I understand from the [lifecycle diagram](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle_Diagram), this should work.

There is a parent Vue instance (which binds to `#main`) and contains a child component (via the `<mod-sidebar>` element in the html).

Now I get the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: v-on:click="gotoSlide" expects a function value, got undefined
```

And the `v-text` directive isn't working either, even though the data is clearly defined.

Thus, the issue seems to be, that the parent instance already compiles all of the directives in the child component as its own (e.g. `v-text` in the child component is already compiled by the parent, before the child is initialized it seems).

Is there any way to prevent that from happening, so that the directives within the custom child tag `<mod-sidebar>` are only compiled by the child element?

```js
Vue.component(`mod-sidebar`, {
    ready: function() {
        // initialize slider
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            name: 'slider',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        gotoSlide: function(event) {
            return false;
        },
    },
    replace: false
});

new Vue({
    el: '#main'
});
```

```html
<main class="skel-main" id="main" role="main"> <!-- parent -->
    <mod-sidebar class="sidebar"> <!-- child -->
        <div class="sidebar--slider">
            <div class="sidebar--slider-item">
                <a class="sidebar--slider-link" href="#" @click="gotoSlide">
                    <span class="sidebar--slider-text" v-text="name"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mod-sidebar>
</main>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtmmeak9/27/

Comment: The thing is that the variables of the HTML inside the `<mod-sidebar>` are in the scope of the parent (the `new Vue(...)` one). You would have to move the link inside this component or the handler to this main object.

Comment: Isn't the link inside the component? And is there no way to tell vue that is should ignore the bindings of child components within the same markup?

Comment: Well, it *is* inside the component (assuming the component has a `<slot>` element, otherwise the content inside the component is ignored). However, it is not treated as being inside the *scope* of the component. That is, the variables all should refer to those of the *parent*.

Comment: Hm, that's too bad (the content inside the component is not ignored, interestingly enough. It is even available as `this.$el` within the child component). So there is no way to have prerendered html as a template for all the components? I really want to avoid having to have separate templates for vue components.

Comment: You can definitely have prerendered HTML as a template for all `<mod-sidebar>` components. Just place the prerendered HTML as a string in the component options (i.e `Vue.component('mod-sidebar', { template: "..." ...`).

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to avoid. Thank you very much for your help, I'll try to find another way to solve this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `inline-template`

```
<mod-sidebar class="sidebar" inline-template>
```